# Export products to a CSV file and post it to a URL/downloadable link

Tags: csv

I work for a digital marketplace and we require our partners to provide us with a CSV file of all their products that is downloadable/posted to a URL and set to be **updated daily** in order to ensure up-to-date product and pricing information is correct for the user.

A lot of our Magento partners are having issues in doing this and I was hoping someone very capable may be able to explain what to do in a step-by-step process? Partners on other e-comm platforms don't seem to have the same issue, so I'd love to help everyone using Magento 2 out!

(I obviously don't have or use Magento, just want to try help out a tonne of people!)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1- write a cron job that generates product csv report daily.

step 2 - you need to setup sftp server also where you can drop your csv files.

Step3 - then use cron class to update/create product if any lattest csv is dropped in sftp then download it to magetno var folder and import it to create/update product.